# Copy dirs with unknown variables?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script dilemma with copying directory structures to alternative locations. We have defined five digit numerals for the main name of a Dir but there is also a varying description, is there any way I can wildcard the description in my copyto path e.g.

```
xcopy <path>Template <path>09999_ParentFolder\<new name> \e
```

The "ParentFolder" is an unknown and may contain spaces, I haven't had any luck with '*'. I want to avoid asking users to type in the exact details if possible, my only other idea is if I can create a selection list of a dir that the user could enter via a numbered selection?

Comment: Something says wildcards wouldn't (shouldn't ?) work with target locations in a copy operation...

Comment: Agreed, if I could avoid Dirs with descriptions life would be so much easier!

Comment: Looking at this another way. I already have vars set for the directory number %jobn% which will be unique is there a way I can search for the unknown element to add to another variable, I know on the command line I can Dir 09999* and I will get a single report with the full name, can this be collected somehow to a named variable?

Comment: Try something like. `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /a:d /b %jobn%*') do if exist "%%~fA echo %%~fA"` or `for /d %%A in ("%jobn%*") do echo %%~fA` just change the echo to set commands.

Answer (score 0):

[List a directory folder to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939268/list-a-directory-folder-to-a-variable/14939993#comment20976053_14939993)

I found the solution to this from my other posting (see link), thanks for your help. :)